# Adams operations and an artificial grading on K-theory

Tags: lie-groups, exterior-algebra, graded-rings, spectral-sequences, k-theory

In [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s3-22.3.562/full) by Snaith (p. 575) appears the following comment:

> ... these transgressive elements [...] can be located by means of the Adams operations [...]. These operate (unstably) in both the
>   algebraic and geometric spectral sequences and for $k = \mathbf Z$ or $\mathbf Q$ effectively strengthen the 'weak' $\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z_2$ grading [on a Rothenberg–Steenrod spectral sequence] to a $\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z$ grading.

I thought I understood what the Adams operations are, but I definitely don't understand this. What is he talking about?

Comment: Alas, your reference is pay-walled.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ba3cba6gisy446b/K-theory_homogeneous_space%28Snaith%2C1971%29.pdf?dl=0

Please don't call the laws on me